# Determine a range is in the set of range?

Tags: c#, .net

I have some sets (10,23), (15,22), (20,25), (29,31), (30, 31).

I have to write a function in C# to determine below scenario.
(22,30) is not in the range.
and (19,23) is in the range.

How to prove (22,30) is not in the range comparing with each existing sets?
at the same time prove (19,23) is in the range.

How can I prove this in c#?

Comment: What is your question? (19,23) is in the range of what?

Comment: What do you mean by "in the range"?

Comment: By (19,23), do you mean 19-23? or 19 & 23?

Comment: for each sets, compare `minValue <= 22 && 22 <= maxValue && minValue <= 30 && 30 <= maxValue`. Same applies for 19 and 23

Answer (score 1):

```
void Main()
{
    List<MyRange> ranges = new List<MyRange> {
        new MyRange{Start=10, End=23},
        new MyRange{Start=15, End=22},
        new MyRange{Start=20, End=25},
        new MyRange{Start=29, End=31},
        new MyRange{Start=30, End=31},
    };

    var testRange1 = new MyRange { Start = 22, End = 30 };
    var testRange2 = new MyRange { Start = 19, End = 23 };

    Console.WriteLine(IsInclusiveRange(testRange1, ranges));
    Console.WriteLine(IsInclusiveRange(testRange2, ranges));


}
private bool IsInclusiveRange(MyRange toTest, IEnumerable<MyRange> ranges)
{
    return ranges.Any(r => r.Start <= toTest.Start && r.End >= toTest.End);
}

class MyRange
{ 
    public int Start { get; set; }
    public int End { get; set; }
}
```